# How do I integrate the equation of a ellipse?

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

How do I integrate this equation with respect to "*x*"? I am quite sure I need to use trigonometric substitution (or even hyperbolic), but I am not good at these methods since I just learned about trigonometric substitution. This is the equation of an ellipse. I know I have to re-write the equation so that it has an "integratable" form, but I struggle to work it out.

[image]

Is this the answer?

[image]

Or is this the answer?
[image]

Comment: At first i would simplify your term!

Comment: Usually, $c=1$.

Comment: Yes, the problem is I am working with c, but I think I got it solved.

Comment: You can also absorb $c$ in $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Factor out $a$, then $c$, to obtain
$$\sqrt{a^2\biggl(c^2-\biggl(\frac{x-h}b\biggr)^{\!\!2\,}\biggr)}=|ac|\sqrt{1-\biggl(\frac{x-h}{bc}\biggr)^{\!\!2\,}}$$
and set $x-h=bc\sin u$, $\;\mathrm dx=bc\cos u\,\mathrm d u$.

Comment: I added my answer to the question. Is it ok?

Comment: Not quite for me; the factor before the brackets is $\frac{|ac|bc}2$, and I don't see where your $kx$ term come from.

Comment: Is the second answer correct then?

Comment: I obtain $\;\frac14|ac|\,bc\biggl(\arcsin\dfrac{x-h}{bc}+\dfrac{x-h}{bc}\sqrt{1-\bigl(\dfrac{x-h}{bc}\Bigr)^2}\biggr)+kx+C$.

Comment: I must have missed .5 somewhere, and my kx was correct. Thanks!